# "Not defined" error when inserting values into MySQL from Python

Tags: python, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I run code with python and the data come from it. I want to save in MySQL RDS but I have error:

```
('Connected to MySQL Server version ', '5.7.26-log')
("You're connected to database: ", (u'attendance1',))
MySQL connection is closed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "v8.py", line 79, in <module>
    mySql_insert_query = ("""INSERT INTO empolyee (ID, Name, date, Similarity) VALUES (%s",%s",%s",%s")""",(n+1, name, date_, smlrty_Prcnt))
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

The code:

```
      import boto3
      import io
      from PIL import Image
      import mysql.connector
      from mysql.connector import Error
      from mysql.connector import errorcode



      n=0
      rekognition = boto3.client('rekognition', region_name='eu-west-1')
      dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='eu-west-1')

      image = Image.open("sample.jpeg")
      stream = io.BytesIO()
      image.save(stream,format="JPEG")
      image_binary = stream.getvalue()


      response = rekognition.search_faces_by_image(
            CollectionId='test_Colction',
            Image={'Bytes':image_binary}
         )


      for match in response['FaceMatches']:
      smlrty_Prcnt = match['Similarity']



    def prnt():
        #global name
        face = dynamodb.get_item(
        TableName='test_Colction_Table',
        Key={'RekognitionId': {'S': match['Face']['FaceId']}}
        )
    if 'Item' in face:
        name = (face['Item']['FullName']['S'])
    if name == 'basem tarek' :
        print'Employee: ', name        
        date_ = response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPHeaders']['date']
        print 'Date: ', date_

     try:
          connection = mysql.connector.connect(*********,
                                         user="******",
                                         passwd="******",
                                         database="attendance1")

    if connection.is_connected():
        db_Info = connection.get_server_info()
        print("Connected to MySQL Server version ", db_Info)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select database();")
        record = cursor.fetchone()
        print("You're connected to database: ", record)

     except Error as e:
          print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)

     try:
         mySql_insert_query = ("""INSERT INTO empolyee (ID, Name, date, Similarity) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)""",(n+1, name, date_, smlrty_Prcnt))

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    result = cursor.execute(mySql_insert_query)
    connection.commit()
    print("Record inserted successfully into  table")
    cursor.close()

      except mysql.connector.Error as error:
          print("Failed to insert record into table {}".format(error))

     finally:
           if (connection.is_connected()):
              connection.close()
              print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

Comment: this does not work I think: if 'Item' in face:
    name = (face['Item']['FullName']['S'])

Comment: Insert a debug (print) line to show the contents of `mySql_insert_query` before executing it.